# How to indicate about a single short story when selling?

Tags: self-publishing, short-story, kindle

For Kindle Direct Publishing, the minimum price you can set is $0.99. I published a short story and wanted to price it at $0.49. This is because it is a short story of about 500 words. Its short and sharp though. Can any one tell me how to indicate that it is a single and not a long story to potential readers? I have always believed that being honest and upfront is always the best policy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the description say "short story - 20 pages" or some such.

Answer (score 3):

I've seen this on the cover of some single short stories:

[title] A short story written by [name].